# Dynamic arrays and unexpected output

Tags: c, c99

I have written this script, and the aim of it is to get in input a phrase and to print just the first word (the one before the first space). I cannot understand why, when I execute it, I get a bunch of numbers in the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 30

/*
Prende in input una frase e stampa la prima parola
*/
char *fw();

int main () {

    int j,i;
    char parola[MAX], *p;

    printf ("Inserisci una stringa: ");
    fgets(parola, MAX, stdin);

    p = fw(&parola, &i);

    for (j=0; j < i; j++){
        printf("%d", p[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}

char *fw(char *parola, int *puntatoreI) {

    int i;
    char *p;

    for (i=0; parola[i]!=' '; i++)
        ;

    p = (char *)malloc((i+1)*sizeof(char));

    for (i=0; parola[i]!=' '; i++){
        p[i] = parola[i];
    }
    p[i+1] = '\0';

    puntatoreI = &i;

    return p;
}
```

Comment: Using `printf("%d",p[j]);` for output, you will only get numbers printed, will you not?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler,  I'm not the one asking the question, so I have to go with what the OP posted.  And (IMO)  posting code is extremely simple.  Just indent every line of the code 4 spaces above what the original source indented the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. ```
   puntatoreI = &i;
   ```

   Is assigning a pointer `puntatoreI` to point to variable `i`. You don't want to do that. You want to modify variable `i` inside `main`, that is where the pointer `puntatoreI` points to. You want:

   ```
   *puntatoreI = i;
   ```
2. You are allocating `(i+1)` characters for `p`. Yet you are assigning to `p[i+1] = '\0';` is accessing 1-byte out of bounds. Just `p[i] = '\0';`. `i` is the last index in an array of `i+1` elements.
3. Using empty braces in function declaration `char *fw();` is very old. To make sure your code is ok, just repeat the function declaration from the definition `char *fw(char *parola, int *puntatoreI);`.
4. The type of `&parola` is `char (*)[30]` - it's a pointer to an array of `30` characters. Yet, the `fw` function takes `char *` - a pointer to char. Just pass `parola` as in `p = fw(parola, &i);`.
5. And finally, to your question:

   > why when I execute it I get a bunch of numbers in output.

   You get a "bunch of numbers" on the output, because you print them with `printf("%d",p[j]);`. `%d` is a `printf` format specifier used to print numbers in base 10. To print characters as they are, use `%c` format specifier. But because `p` should point to a zero-terminated array of characters (to a string), you could do just `printf("%s", p);` instead of the whole loop.